# Google Appscript selecting incorrect Sheet even after explicitly specifying

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-forms

So, I'm working on a small script that recieves a google form response then depending on it looks for a certain value in a sheet and deletes it. But the issue that I'm facing is that for some reason, even after explicitly specifying which sheet to use, I get the following error whenever if I happen to have another worksheet selected:

```
Exception: Array is empty: values
WTOUpdate   @ Code.gs:35
updateForm  @ Code.gs:70
```

Here's the function:

```
function WTOUpdate() {
    let WTO_list = form.getItemById('18116013').asListItem();
    let WTO_countries = [];
    let WTO_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('UNGA Countries');
    let WTOCountries = ss.getRange("A36:A104").getValues();
    for (i = 0; i < WTOCountries.length; i++) {
      if (WTOCountries[i][0] !== '') {
        WTO_countries.push(WTOCountries[i][0])
      }
    }
    WTO_list.setChoiceValues(WTO_countries)
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're using wrong variable (kind of typo).

Change

`let WTOCountries = ss.getRange("A36:A104").getValues();`

to

`let WTOCountries = WTO_sheet.getRange("A36:A104").getValues();`